# How to configure the back stack when activity is launched by BroadcastReceiver?

Tags: android, android-broadcastreceiver

I have an app with `MainActivity.java` which has a button that when clicked launches `Main2Activity.java`. `Main2Activity.java` is added to the project in Android Studio using New/Activity/Basic Activity. It has a back arrow at the top and touching it will return the app to `MainActivity`. `AndroidManifest.xml` has the following for `Main2Activity`:

```
android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity"
```

The app also has a `BroadcastReceiver` which, after performing its work, launches `Main2Activity.java`.  When started this way (when the app is in the background), the back arrow in `Main2Activity` does not go back to `MainActivity` but instead exits the app.

I would like the back function of `Main2Activity` to always go to `MainActivity`.  According to [Navigate up with a new back stack](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/ancestral.html#BuildBackStack), there seems a way to do this, but the example is meant for an activity launched by *another* app.

How do I set the back destination for an activity launced by a `BroadcastReceiver`?

Comment: An not that grace way is override onBackPressed. If Main2Activity is launched by broadcast, start MainActivity manually, else just normal navigation back.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways of doing this:

1. [Providing the Up Navigation](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/ancestral.html#BuildBackStack) as mentioned in the link quoted by you in the question. It should work even when you're navigating to the Activity through a broadcast.
2. Use [startActivities](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/temporal.html#CreateBackStack) from the BroadcastReceiver to start both MainActivity and Main2Activity. This allows you to create a backstack when starting an Activity and it's parent is not on the stack.

I prefer approach 2 simply because it works even when you press the hardware back, not just the back button on the Action Bar. For achieving that with approach 1, you'd also have to override onBackPressed.